# Typescript Timeout type number is not assignable to type Timeout when using ReturnType

Tags: typescript

The code below is creating the following typescript error.

`Conversion of type 'number' to type 'Timeout' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first`

```js
const t: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = setTimeout(
  () => reload([args]),
  searchDelay
)
```

Clearly this doesn't make any sense!

Comment: `setTimeout` returns just a number. You can use `const t: number = ...`. In fact, its not even needed to add an type to `t` because the type gets inherited

Comment: what version of TS are you using?